# VS2010 syntax coloring: how to obtain the previous classification type

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mef, visual-studio-sdk

I'm trying to play with the new syntax coloring capabilities of VS2010 based on Noah Richards' diff coloring sample. The goal is to create syntax coloring for SpecFlow (http://www.specflow.org).

In my case, finding the syntax elements are fairly complex and not line-level. Therefore, when I implement the GetClassificationSpans I don't want to re-parse the entire file, but rather take the state of the beginning of the changed text and parsing the content from that point on.

I thought that I can get the previous classifications as ClassificationTags. I did this using the IBufferTagAggregatorFactoryService class.

It works, but I'm not sure whether this is the best way to go. Shall I create only tag aggregator for the entire classifier class or I can create it every time when GetClassificationSpans is called? Shall I create a special tag to remember the parsing state?

Maybe this is anyway not the right way to go, I'm also interested in other suggestions.

Br,
Gaspar

Edit: I've found a good article series in the topic: http://www.hill30.com/MikeFeingoldBlog/index.php/2009/07/31/django-editor-in-vs-2010-part-1-colors/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, you'll have to remember the state yourself.  Most VS language services keep a state cookie for the beginning of each line that they update on text change.

At any point, getting classifications (through either a classifier aggregator or tag aggregator) will always result into a call into the current classifiers/taggers, so it won't be returning any type of cached state (or the "last" classifications returned).  The editor doesn't really cache this information, and just acts as a dumb pass-through for the information your classifier provides to the visible lines being formatted.

Also, If you do it from a classifier (provided by either an IClassifierProvider or ITaggerProvider), you are setting yourself up for some nasty recursion, especially if your classifier responds to `GetClassificationSpans` by calling into the aggregator (which then calls back into your classifier for some earlier text, etc.).  If your classifier *needs* to consume other classifications to work correctly (and not its own classifications), the only safe way to write that is to:

1. Implement your "classifier" as an `ITagger<IClassificationTag>`, and provide it from an `IViewTaggerProvider`.
2. Grab an `ITagAggregator<IClassificationTag>` from an `IBufferTagAggregatorFactoryService`, but only once.
3. Implement `IDisposable` on your tagger and dispose the tag aggregator in `Dispose()`.

Comment: thx for the answer! about the state cookies: is there any built-in infrastructure for that or shall I just store them in my own model?

Comment: There was in the old interfaces (`IVsColorizer`), but not in the new ones, so you'll have to write your own model.  Let me know if you run into any problems, though, as I had to write such a model when shimming these old `IVsColorizer`s so they'd work with classification.