# How to get IClassifier for the standard classification type?

Tags: c++, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-sdk

I have an extension to the MS Visual Studio editor which adds some syntax highlighting to the C++.

I want to ensure that provided SnapshotSpan has standard classification type ("comment"). There are several ways to do this:

**1**. I can manually parse C++ code to find comment spans. This is a last option I want to use :)

**2**. I can use a hack:

```
this.colorer = buffer.Properties.PropertyList // <-- buffer is a ITextBuffer
    .Select(p => p.Value as IClassifier) // Get all classifiers someone put into the properies of the current text buffer
    .Where(i => i != null)
    .Where(i => i.GetType().FullName == "Microsoft.VisualC.CppColorer") // <-- Hack
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now I can use this colorer (which is internal Microsoft implementation of the C++ classifier) in the following way:

```
this.colorer.GetClassificationSpans(span)
    .Where(s => s.ClassificationType.Classification == FormatNames.Comment ||
                s.ClassificationType.Classification == FormatNames.XmlDocComment)
```

Tada! I have information about comments in text buffer. As you understand, this a hack and I want to avoid this :)

**3**. I can try to get (somehow) classifier for the standard classification type (for example, for "comment").

---

So my question is: **Is this possible to get IClassifier by classification type name?**

Comment: For VS2022, the hack mostly still works. However, the `"Microsoft.VisualC.CppColorer"` element in the `PropertyList` is no longer an `IClassifier` but an `ITagger<IClassificationTag>`. Also, the two possible names of the classification of that tagger are `"comment"` and `"XML Doc Comment"`, if anyone wonders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no official way to do that. So I implemented classifier for code comments by myself.

Answer (score 3):

You can import the `IClassifierAggregatorService`:

```
[Import]
internal IClassifierAggregatorService classifierAggregatorService = null;
```

And then iterate over `ClassificationSpan` to check that every classification span is of type `"comment"`:

```
IClassifier classifier = classifierAggregatorService.GetClassifier(textBuffer);
IList<ClassificationSpan> classificationSpanList = _classifier.GetClassificationSpans(span);
foreach (ClassificationSpan classificationSpan in classificationSpanList)
{
    if (classificationSpan.ClassificationType.IsOfType("comment"))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As an alternative to getting the `IClassifierAggregatorService`, you can get an `ITagAggregator<IClassificationTag>` from `IBufferTagAggregatorFactoryService`. Especially useful if you want to add classification depending on a previous classification (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3160517/1329277)).